# Is there any reason I should stick strictly to "data-" attributes for custom attributes?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

Like the title says, is there any reason I can't create arbitrary names for my own attributes?

Comment: Besides a desire to keep your HTML valid? No.

Comment: Future-proof comes out of mind. If you use a random name and a latter version of HTML happens to include it, your page is suddenly changed in an unexpected way. Data attributes are guarranted to remain application-specific.

Comment: Search engines might penalise you if the site uses unknown tags and attributes, too. Data prevents that, if that's the case.

Comment: They also won't make a validator choke.

Comment: If other devs work with your codebase, it would be easier for them. Since using `data-` is a well known standard.

Comment: Good points, but @Alejandro on future proofing it's no different with data-attributes as you may use some other js library that used the same ones you did. Of all the concerns, this one is the least of them to me. Supposing a conflict "did" happen here, it would be a simple matter of using find/replace to update and if you have a really large application it might, you know, take an hour. More likely it will take you less than 10 minutes plus time to test.

Comment: @BVernon I strongly disagree con your optimism about fix time for such a conflict :) I find it difficult to even know that a conflict happened in the first place. Good point about libraries, didn't even consider that as a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

1. Clean "namespace": You don't need to restrict yourself about which attributes you can use. `data-bgcolor` is safe to use, `bgcolor` is not.
2. Semantics: The way data and non-data attributes are accessed is different. Usually, attributes will be retrieved using `el.getAttribute("value")`, while data attributes will be access with `el.dataset.value`. This is no confusion about what the attribute does (is it visual or not).
3. It's standard: HTML5 declares a specific set of valid attributes. Going against standards should generally be avoided.

Comment: I really don't care about 1) and 3) (I just mean I've never been one to follow rules based on "just because" reasoning), but point 2 is compelling... actually I didn't even know you could do that, so thanks!